# set the length of the column separation rule in multicols

Tags: two-column, rules, multicol

I have trouble to make the line which separates two columns in a multicols environment reaching the bottom of the columns.

```
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
```

is managing the rule width. Is there any command to set the rule length?

My code and the output

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ucs}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{setspace} % pr utiliser spacing
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \textbf{Exercice 1}\\ Factoriser au maximum les expressions suivantes.
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=150pt]
    \item $15y^2-5yz-6y+2z$
    \item $y^2+12y+35$
    \item $25y^2-40y+16$
    \item $t^2-2t-8$ 
    \item $z^3+3y^3+3z^2y+zy^2$
    \item $81x^2-90x+25$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

[image: column separation rule]

I can manage it through some fancy ad hoc manipulations. Any elegant idea to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the vertical line **is going** until the end of each column.  Your problem is that the end of each column is not where you think: there is no extra space left after the last question of each column.  This is because you're using `\itemsep`.

I changed your code a bit, replacing `\itemsep` with a new macro `\extraspace` that leaves the intended amount of vertical space.  Notice the use of `\columnbreak`; if you leave it out, the fourth question will be at the bottom of the left column.  I also cleaned several unused packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\newcommand{\extraspace}{\vspace*{150pt}}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Exercice 1}\\ Factoriser au maximum les expressions suivantes.
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $15y^2-5yz-6y+2z$    \extraspace
  \item $y^2+12y+35$         \extraspace
  \item $25y^2-40y+16$       \extraspace
  \columnbreak
  \item $t^2-2t-8$           \extraspace
  \item $z^3+3y^3+3z^2y+zy^2$ \extraspace
  \item $81x^2-90x+25$       \extraspace
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]